# How can we convert below code in RxJava Code

Tags: java, rx-java

```
public List<CustomerDTO> getCustomerSalaryByDepartmentNumber(String departmentNumber) {
    List<CustomerDTO> customers = customerService.getCustomerSalaryByDepartmentNumber(departmentNumber);

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(customers)) {
       for (CustomerDTO customer : customers) {
          customerService.updateCustomDataOne(customer);
          customerService.updateCustomDataTwo(customer);
       }
    }
    return customers;
}
```

I am new to RxJava and trying to understand the concept of Observables
I want to refactor above simple code in Rx Java and don't want to use `Observable.just(customers);`  at the end of the method. if someone can point me in right direction it would be helpful.

Please look at the following code and provide suggestion.

```
public Observable<Object> getCustomerSalaryByDepartmentNumber(String departmentNumber) {

    Observable<List<CustomerDTO>> customersObservable = Observable.just(departmentNumber).map(dnum -> {
       return customerService.getCustomerSalaryByDepartmentNumber(dnum);
    });

    return customersObservable.map(customers -> {
       return Observable.from(customers).map( customer -> {
           return Observable.zip(
                Observable.just(customerService.updateCustomDataOne(customer)), 
                Observable.just(customerService.updateCustomDataTwo(customer)), 
                (r, u) -> {
                   customer.setCustomDataOne(r.getCustomDataOne());
                   return customer;
                });
       });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit confusing, because your two methods above do different things. 
In the imperative version, you're not using the return value of your `updateCustomData` methods, nor are you calling the `setCustomDataOne` method.

If you want a direct `Observable` conversion of the first method, then how about the following:

```
public Observable<CustomerDTO> getCustomerSalaryByDepartmentNumber(String departmentNumber) {
        return Observable.from(customerService.getCustomerSalaryByDepartmentNumber(departmentNumber))
                .doOnNext(customer -> {
                    customerService.updateCustomDataOne(customer);
                    customerService.updateCustomDataTwo(customer);
                });
    }
```

Note the usage of `Observable.from(List<T>)` which will return an `Observable` that will emit each element of the `list` in order. Doing this negates the need to check if an empty list.

With respect to the second method, the creation and usage of the `customersObservable` object is redundant so can be replaced with the following:

```
public Observable<CustomerDTO> getCustomerSalaryByDepartmentNumber(String departmentNumber) {
        return Observable.from(customerService.getCustomerSalaryByDepartmentNumber(departmentNumber)
                .map(customer -> {
                    return Observable.zip(
                            Observable.just(customerService.updateCustomDataOne(customer)),
                            Observable.just(customerService.updateCustomDataTwo(customer)),
                            (r, u) -> {
                                customer.setCustomDataOne(r.getCustomDataOne());
                                return customer;
                            });
                });
}
```

Be careful that `customerService.updateCustomDataxxx` returns something **not void**. `Observable.zip` won't execute the zipping function until all Observables being zipped emit something. This has caught me out many times.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.